# Same code with different values on the same page, when scrolltop

Tags: jquery, scroll, delay

I'm not showing the whole code, it;s integrated with the cms custom tags, but here's the basic problem. I have the following scroll code:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (top < 174) $(".nav-wrap").css({top: '0', position: 'relative'}),
             $("#cssmenu > ul ul#cm-cur").addClass( "cm-cur" ); //making dropdown ul menu visible

        else $(".nav-wrap").css({top: '0px', position: 'fixed'}),
             $("#cssmenu > ul ul#cm-cur").removeClass( "cm-cur" ); // hide dropdown ul menu when scroll
    });
});
```

And the next one:

```
$( "#cssmenu > ul li.active#drop" ).mouseout(function() {
    t = setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("li.cur-page#drop").css({background: '#EDF1F7'});
        }, 2000);
});
```

And I'm trying to paste two times the second code into the first one, using different values:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       var top = $(document).scrollTop();
       if (top < 174) $(".nav-wrap").css({top: '0', position: 'relative'}),
            $("#cssmenu > ul ul#cm-cur").addClass( "cm-cur" ), //making dropdown ul menu visible
            $( "#cssmenu > ul li.active#drop" ).mouseout(function() {
                t = setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $("li.cur-page#drop").css({background: '#EDF1F7'});
                    }, 2000);
            });

       else $(".nav-wrap").css({top: '0px', position: 'fixed'}),
            $("#cssmenu > ul ul#cm-cur").removeClass( "cm-cur" ), // hide dropdown ul menu when scroll
            $( "#cssmenu > ul li.active#drop" ).mouseout(function() {
                t = setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $("li.cur-page#drop").css({background: 'none'}),
                    $("#cssmenu > ul li ul#cm-cur").removeClass( "cm-cur" ); // after menu hovered, this dropdown ul disapeares, but with delay
                    }, 2000);
            });
    });
});
```

It doesn't work

Comment: You have invalid JavaScript. You should see errors in the console log. Your if / else statement needs curly brackets and your line endings need to semi colons not commas

Comment: Thank you. If it's not hard for you, could you fix it? I really suck at js((